# Looking for current review article on the Oort Cloud

Tags: astrophysics, resource-recommendations, solar-system

I'm sure someone will tell me just to Google, but I'm struggling to find a truly detailed and informative article explicating our current understanding of the [Oort Cloud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oort_cloud).

Could someone please recommend an arXiv article or perhaps a textbook section?

Comment: Maybe include the resource recommendation tag. I think I reversed the words of this tag for someone, maybe yourself, sorry :), previously regarding this tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rickman (2014)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2014M%26PS...49....8R) reviews the relationship between the Oort cloud and long period comets, but does touch on the origins of the Oort cloud.

The review of [Jewitt (2010)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010IAUS..263....3J) deals with the Oort cloud, Kuiper belt and comets (basically, icy bodies in the solar system), highlighting what we don't know.

The Annual Reviews articles by [Mumma & Charnley (2011)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011ARA%26A..49..471M) and by [Adams (2010)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ARA%26A..48...47A) discuss the chemistry of comets and what they tell us about the Oort cloud and Kuiper belt, and the origins of the Oort cloud and what constraints it puts on the birth environment of the solar system respectively.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks